# Prove that if $S$ be a subset of $Ord$. Show that $Ord\setminus S$ is order-isomorphic to $Ord$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Let $S$ be a subset of $Ord$ where $Ord$ denotes the ordinal class. I aim to show that $Ord\setminus S$ is order-isomorphic to $Ord$.

I have spent some time on this question. The question seems not easy enough for me  and I do not even know how to get start. So could someone please help? Thanks a lot!

EDIT:Now I notice that it is quite possible for the question to be related to the theorem:[image]

And again I am stuck...I am wondering how I can find the relation between some class and some initial segement to apply the theorem. And to disprove one of (i) and (ii), maybe I need to find a contradiction. But so far I cannot see what is the contradiction here I am looking for.

So I am asking for help. Could someone please give some explicit explaination? Thanks so much!

EDIT: I am wondering why it is voted to be closed. If someone who can give some thoughts on this question provided some more details are added, I am always glad to edit my post. I am a beginner of MK set theory who appreciate rather detailed answer. Thanks for patient.

Comment: Given any two well-ordered classes, by transfinite induction one can show that one of them is order-isomorphic to an initial segment of the other. The only thing more you need to show here is that $Ord\setminus S$ doesn't run out of elements before $Ord$.

Comment: Sorry I have tried but maybe because I am not familiar enough to some techniques, I have not work it out yet. Am I on the right track to regard this question(see the edited question)? May I please ask for an answer?

Comment: You don't want to disprove anything here. The classes $A$ and $B$ in the theorem are $Ord$ and $Ord\setminus S$. As a subclass of $Ord, Ord\setminus S$ is also well-ordered. Thus either it is isomorphic to a segment $Ord$ or $Ord$ is isomorphic to a segment of it, or both. But if $Ord \setminus S$ is isomorphic to a strict segment of $Ord$ then there is a least element of $Ord$ which is not in the isomorphism image, Which implies that all of $Ord \setminus S$ is less than some ordinal, and so is a set. But $S$ is also a set, and their union is $Ord$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Then is that the fact that we can conclude that then by the union of sets is a set, so $Ord$ is a set and hence we get a contradiction, and hence $Ord\setminus S$ cannot be isomorphic to any strict initial segment of $Ord$, it must be order isomorphic to the whole $Ord$ class?

Comment: That proves that $Ord \setminus S$ is not isormorphic to a segment of $Ord$. You also have to prove that $Ord$ is not isomorphic to a segment of $Ord \setminus S$. While it may seem obvious that it couldn't be, it cannot just be assumed.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I am considering how to formally prove it. Is it by contradiction or there is some way better? Also I am concerning how to see the fact that if Ord∖S is isomorphic to a strict segment of Ord then there is a least element of Ord which is not in the isomorphism image. May I please ask for some explaination?

Comment: Let $Q = Ord \setminus h(Ord \setminus S)$, where $h$ is the isomorphism. If $h(Ord \setminus S)$ is a strict segment ("proper" is the better term), then it is not all of $Ord$, so $Q$ is non-empty. Since $Ord$ is well-ordered, $Q$ has a least element $\alpha$. Since $h(Ord \setminus S)$ is an initial segment, $\alpha$ cannot be less than anything in it. Ergo, $h(Ord \setminus S) \subset \alpha$ and is thus a set. For the full proof, have you examined user254665's post?

Comment: @PaulSinclair I have tried the solution below, and found that it is only for ZF. Could you please tell me if your argument is okay for MK?

Comment: You are mistaken. user254665's solution is perfectly acceptable in MK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1). If $T$ is a set of ordinals then  there cannot be  an injection $f:Ord$  \ $T \to U$ for any set $U$.

Else, $V= \{u\in U:\exists a\in Ord$  \ $T\; (u=f(a))\}$ is a set, so $\{f^{-1}(v):v\in V\} \cup T=Ord$ is a set. (But then $Ord +1=Ord \cup \{Ord\}$ is an ordinal that's larger than any ordinal.)

(2). Let $A=Ord$ and $B=Ord$ \ $S$ where $S\subset Ord$ is a set.

(i). Suppose $h:A\to B$  where $h$ is an order-isomorphic embedding of $A$ onto an initial segment of $B.$  Then by (1),(with $T=\phi$), we know that   $h(A)$ cannot be a proper initial segment of $B$. That is, $\forall b\in B\;(h(A)\ne \{c\in B:c<b\}.$ So $h(A)=B.$

(ii). Suppose $g:B\to A$ is an order-isomorphic embedding of $B$ onto an initial segment of $A.$  Then by (1),(with $T=S$), we know that $g(B)$ cannot be a proper initial segment of  $A.$ So $g(B)=A.$

(3). Another method  would be to take the transitive (Mostowki) collapse of $B=Ord$ \ $S$. That is, for $b\in B$  let $t(b)=\{ t(c): b>c\in B\}.$ (E.g. $t(\min B)=0$ and $t(\min (B$ \ $\{\min B\})=1$).

Use transfinite induction on $B$ to show that  $t(B)\subset  Ord$ and that $t$ is an order-isomorphic embedding. Then use transfinite induction on $Ord$ to show that $t(B)\supset Ord.$

Comment: Could you please give some explaination on why the preimage is a set?

Comment: Since $f $ is injective we have $\forall v\in V\exists! a\; (f(a)=v)\}. $ By Replacement $\exists W \forall a \;(\psi (a)\implies a\in W)$, where $\psi (a)$ is: $\exists v\in V\;(f(a)=v).$   By Comprehension  there exists $X=\{a\in W\;(\psi (a)\;)\}.$.. Of course $X=f^{-1}V.$

Comment: Note that Comprehension is also applied to the def'n of $V$  to show that $V$ is a set.

Comment: Is it the axiom of replacement in ZF? Actually here we are trying to work with MK.

Comment: I think your edit about MK came after my answer, which is for ZF.

Comment: That is possible. But may I please ask if this answer can be applied in MK after some modification?

Comment: I think all the part except the argument that $V$ and $X$ are sets are ok for MK.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Morse-Kelly. All I know is that MK exists.

Comment: Thanks for patience. I will ask it in another question.

Comment: If $f^{-1}(V)$ were not a set, then there is an injection $\phi: {\scr V} \to f^{-1}(V)$, where $\scr V$ is the universe of sets (Axiom of Limitation of Size). But then $f\circ \phi : {\scr V} \to U$ is also an injection, which cannot be because $U$ is a set by assumption.