# Use MK to prove that no injection from a proper class to a set.

Tags: set-theory

I have seen that it can be done in ZF with the axiom of replacement. But may I ask if it is true in MK? I spent some time on it but now I am so confused. Could someone please tell me how to deal with that? Thanks so much!

Comment: What is MK? (Maybe known to many but not me..)

Comment: @coffeemath It is Morse Kelley set theory.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I'll look...

Comment: @coffeemath Or I would very appreciate if you can prove the weaker result: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2246860/prove-there-cannot-be-an-injection-ford-t-to-u-for-any-set-u Or this even more specific question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2243941/prove-that-if-s-be-a-subset-of-ord-show-that-ord-setminus-s-is-order-isom#comment4618237_2243941 The only problem I have is that what I am allowed to use is MK instead ZF.

Comment: So far I haven't learned enough about MK to be able to help much on either of the weaker results of your last comment. But the question seems interesting anyway...

Comment: Isn't Limitation of Size pretty standard with MK? Wouldn't that rule it out immediately?

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Sorry I do not know about it, may I please ask for an more explicit explaination?

Comment: @MaliceVidrine I have stuck on it for quite a period of time, so I will really appreciate if you give an answer.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine It intuitively makes sense but now I need a formal proof.

Answer (score 1):

Morse-Kelley usually comes with the [Axiom of Limitation of Size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_limitation_of_size), which states that $X$ is a proper class if and only if there's a (class) injection $V\rightarrowtail X$. As every class, set or proper, comes with an inclusion into the universe, and MK has enough expressive power to run the Schroeder-Bernstein argument on classes, there's at least one bijection between any two proper classes. Hence the injection of any proper class into a class $X$ implies an injection from $V$ into $X$, which is exactly the condition that makes something a proper class in MK.

I believe the situation is the same if you replace Limitation of Size with Replacement; if you replace it with Separation, though, I *believe* you can no longer show that injection from a proper class implies proper classhood. I wouldn't quote me on that last bit, though.